Analysing a 2kW bridge amplifier
I was hoping to get some help analysing this circuit which I found here. (https://www.elcircuit.com/2017/11/diy-high-power-amplifier-2000w-2sc5200-2sa1943.html)
I've tried recreating this circuit in LTspice and have had no luck (Yes I traced it). However even if I can't get it working in LTSPICE (I think the circuit might be misdrawn), I just have a bunch of questions regarding the various sub circuits for frequency compensation, feedback and other small things I've never really seen in my 3 years of engineering. I've tried to read up on it and use chatGPT and it's helped but I'm still struggling quite a bit and still don't really understand what's cooking. Here's the LTSPICE circuit which I've redrawn (Much neater than picture below)
https://github.com/Reece-Bird/Files-to-share
All 11 of my questions are in the second picture along side the circuit in question



C3/R3 makes no sense.

There is no indication that this is a legitimate design that the author had built and got working. That whole site looks sus. I would not bother with anything posted there.

It's what I was thinking, but I wasnt sure. Thanks for confirming

There are a number of problems with this circuit. I’ll address a few of them.
C2 is not connected. I’m not sure where it’s supposed to be connected.
R3 and C3 are supposed to be connected to the output of the first opamp, this is the feedback for the opamp and along with R1 will determine it’s gain at ~4.3.
Transistor Q6 looks like the VAS (voltage amplifier stage) and transistor Q4 looks like a \$V_{BE}\$ multiplier to set the bias.
The 10 ohm resistor is not in parallel with the speaker, it goes from one side of the speaker to ground while the speaker is not connected to ground. I’m not sure why this was done.
And yes, the Zeners are regulators for the opamps.
The whole thing looks a bit suspect, I will have to try to simulate it and see what else I can find, but start with what I’ve given you and see where that gets you, then you might want to ask new, more focused questions, ideally you should ask one answerable question at a time.

yeah, the only explanation I can see is that whoever made this circuit for that website didn't design that amplifier themselves, but copied a bad scan of a schematic from paper. There's more indication of that, like the bad scan of the PCB layout on the same website. OP would probably be well-advised to instead of spending money and time on this schematic, which might end up being wrong, to get a book on Audio power amplifier design. Douglas Self's Audio Power Amplifier Design Handbook might be a good start, and it's available.

@MarcusMüller Agreed, and they should have a look at the diyaudio site, plenty of info and well tested designs there.

Ah thanks for the recommendations, will try get a copy of the book now and I'll have a peruse of the website Marcus mentioned. Also what do you mean by more new, focused questions? Not trying to be rude, this is just the first time using this forum and i'm not really sure what the etiquette is?
